# Book on IR products in 2024?

Tags: interest-rates, books

After the Libor->RFR transition, I am a bit worried about reading books like Andersen&Piterbarg or Mercurio/Brigo.

They're still highly useful of course since its mostly models being studied and then applied to real-world products later, but written before the transition, and now we're having to read research papers to adapt existing models to the new reality.

I don't expect there to be books as great as those two written already in a post-Libor world, but are there any other books that still offer a good overview of IR products and models from a modern perspective?